# How to wait for key press in perl script?

Tags: perl

I am trying to execute a binary using the following command :

```
system("update");
```

After executing "update" command, the system prompts the following :

```
"Press ENTER to exit:"
```

How do I implement the above in my perl script?

Comment: Do you mean you want too implement a similar prompt or do you want to be able too respond too the prompt?

Answer (score 29):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Press ENTER to exit:";
<STDIN>;
```

Comment: You may also have to set `$|` to something other than `undef` or `0`. Otherwise, the output gets buffered, and depending upon the system, it might not do quite what you want.

Comment: Terminal output doesn't get buffered. Am I missing something?

Comment: @user2493235 I was using `$|` set to Null to read from a socket, where protocol packets were null-separated. Afterwards, trying to read from <STDIN> like above would keep reading until I either entered the null character (Ctrl+shift+@) or EOF (ctrl+D) - pressing enter had no effect. Setting `#|` to "\n" solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
#! usr/bin/perl
print "How old are you?";
$age = <>;
print "WOW! You are $age years old!";
```